# protect a wordpress url with .htaccess password method

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

I have  a WordPress site, where I want to restrict user access for certain URLs (i.e site.com/training/private and all the URLs that follows /private/) through .htacces method

I have used the below method

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/private/" noauth
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Identify yourself"
AuthUserFile /pathto/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=noauth

Satisfy any
```

This doesn't seem to work, any workaround for this method to work?

Comment: What version of apache are you using ?

Comment: Apache Version is 2.2.29